# Keep `?:` types optional when looping over them

Tags: typescript

I made a type that makes all properties except for the ones that I specifically pick not required.

```
export type OptionalProps<Input, Excl extends keyof Input> = {
    [P in Exclude<keyof Input, Excl>]: Input[P];
} &
    Optional<Input>;
```

The problem is, it will make `?:` properties defined if I don't specify them directly.

I tried `undefined extends Input[P]  ? '' : Input[P]`, but that didn't work, it just assigns `''` as the type. Assigning undefined forces me then to always provide undefined.

Not sure how to map outside of `[]`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHlKgJYHsB2BDANgHgJLqQCuoAfLALywDewAkANoAKsy6sA1tOKgGaxCJUAF0A-AC5BRUixEBuYAF9FYKHEQoMOZgCdUkAM4EZoADSwAogA8AxtljRroaOgAmhrj37ThFanRMrOxWdtjEbtC43LwCQqQWNvZkIlLxoHKKSrAAZAyaaFh46WSqEDCwALLg8ABGAFbQtqBUtMCwHbAAtuAAcphd0JKwhqC67ADmZu2dPQAymKP9g1Kj4+hTMx09AIIT0FLoxF210LrKILYYo901DU2gEgXa2HoGxtV1jc0WAETzi1Ay2gv38bU6tz2B1gACYAAzTToAeiRt2BUl+tV00AAFr9YLhqKcroNPJE+OxoG5lEA)

Comment: Could you please share reproducable example and explicitly define what are you expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to take a type `T` and a union of its keys `K` and produce a new type where the properties at the keys in `K` are unchanged, but the ones not in `K` are all made optional, I'd be inclined to write it like this:

```
type PartialExceptFor<T, K extends keyof T> =
  Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>;
```

Here we are just using the provided [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) like `Pick`, `Partial`, and `Omit` to compose the type you're looking for.  Let's test it:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c?: string;
  d?: number;
}

type FB = PartialExceptFor<Foo, "b" | "d">;
// type FB = Pick<Foo, "b" | "d"> & Partial<Pick<Foo, "a" | "c">>
```

That is correct although it's hard to tell by looking at the IntelliSense quick info for the type.  One way to deal with this is to force the compiler to walk through the properties and produce a single, expanded object type:

```
type PartialExceptFor<T, K extends keyof T> =
  Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

The `extends infer O` part is using [inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to "copy" the type into a new type parameter `O`, which we then map each property to itself via `{ [P in keyof O]: O[P] }`.

Now the quick-info in IntelliSense gives you this:

```
type FB = PartialExceptFor<Foo, "b" | "d">;
/* type FB = {
    b: number;
    d?: number | undefined;
    a?: string | undefined;
    c?: string | undefined;
} */
```

That's what we wanted.  The properties `b` and `d` have not been changed (`b` is still required and `d` is still optional), but the remainder of the properties, `a` and `c`, have been made optional.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwKIA8DGEzABiA9ggDwAqANFANJQRbAQB2AJgM5QDWEIxAMygUAfFAC8AKCixkObpRq0xAMliIU6MgHkAtsmCK6IsY2bsuyFgIgIo2qAH4oAbygBtGFCs8+g+wC6AFz2ngFQAL5QISwQAG62ANySklbMCAJweFAkxK7SUHAhHMAIVgDmyTIARjEArrrVSQU4jsWlFVVQbG1QLA1NCMkRKaCQOQBCEupIqJi4+ESkZLk0AETVa1AAPlBrbGsiyQD0x1Bj0IRT4rLyK8TE65s7eweqM5poZDByCqt7cC2uzWOEOIhSkmOACpzuBLtd8jIavVGs0kd1ev1UXZdnV2BABFYIGwujI4L0SmUWOUXni2ASiSSCjJWu0qTTcfjCbEmVEoccUkA)

Comment: Awesome answer! I have to switch around `pick` and `omit` to get the desired result (the key input is like a whitelist for what is supposed to become partial, right now the key input is a whitelist for stuff that should not become partial, but that was difficult to see / unclear because of how I asked my question )